# iCloud still full after deleting lots of messages

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, icloud, storage, space

My iCloud was full, mostly due to messages.

[image]

So, I deleted the biggest message files, reducing the space down to 1.78GB.

[image]

However, it still says my iCloud is full - on my phone, laptop and on icloud.com, even though there should be 2.62 extra GB free.

Comment: reboot makes effects?

Answer (score 1):

Wait for some time and check again. It may take a little while for the messages to be purged on the iCloud servers and for the updated storage space to be reported on the device.

Comment: Thanks!! Its been 24 hours but i'll wait some more and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

There might be too many pictures in Messages.
The warning that iCloud is full usually appears when automatic iCloud backup is triggered. You could try turning off iCloud backup on iPhone and you won't receive this message.